# AWS Product Advertising API ItemSearch Bad Request

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

I am trying to use Amazon Product Advertising API. I did add WDSL inside my project but I have a problem when I send the request. It just gives bad request exception.

```
 try
        {
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
            binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
            this.Proxy = new AWSECommerceServicePortTypeClient(
            binding,
            new EndpointAddress("https://webservices.amazon.com/onca/soap?Service=AWSECommerceService"));
            this.Proxy.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new AmazonSigningEndpointBehavior(accessKeyId, secretKey));
            this.ListOfResult = new List<string>();
            ItemSearchRequest request = new ItemSearchRequest();
            request.SearchIndex = "Books";
            request.Title = "WCF";
            request.ResponseGroup = new string[] { "Small" };

            ItemSearch itemSearch = new ItemSearch();
            itemSearch.Request = new ItemSearchRequest[] { request };
            itemSearch.AWSAccessKeyId = accessKeyId;
            itemSearch.AssociateTag = "-21";

            // issue the ItemSearch request
            ItemSearchResponse response = this.Proxy.ItemSearch(itemSearch);

            // write out the results
            foreach (var item in response.Items[0].Item)
            {
                this.ListOfResult.Add(item.ItemAttributes.Title);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

Comment: Can you give more information about what you are doing with AWS and what resources you have? There are tons of resources. Did you set you inbound firewall on you security group?

Comment: I think it is not about inbound firewall ? I am just trying to use AWS Product Advertising API.

Comment: I haunt use that resource but so far every resource I have used has a security group associated and the default restricts it to not allow external ip  addresses. So I would check your security group first .unless you can telnet to the port and get a response